# rotate UIView with correct offset added on a UIWindow as per orientation change

Tags: iphone, objective-c, orientation

So I've a `UIView`, which is added on the main window of my application. The `UIView` doesn't necessarily cover the entire screen.
Upon orientation change, I adjust this `UIView` as per the new orientation with the new x-y offset values.
The code was working correctly, until I started testing on iPad.Now the problem is, the `UIView` upon rotation doesn't maintain the offset correctly, and upon new rotation seems to bounce across the screen.
Has someone solved this problem of "maintaining the correct offset when rotating the `UIView`"?
I can share the piece of code being used currently.

Comment: Either show your code or show your UI screenshot .... I would be more clear before answering.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to maintain a specific offset you need to define how your view should behave when it's parent view frame is changing. This is done by specifying the `autoresizingMask` property of UIView correctly. Have a look to the different mask you can apply [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html).

Comment: @Vakul,Tiguero: I'm not sure how will autoresizing mask work here.
Basically to rotate a UIView added on the window object, I am setting a NSNotification for orientation change. And then trying to transform the view as per the new orientation.
A part of code is [here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/4902546/code.rtf)

Comment: So this code takes care of basic rotation according to the interface orientation, but just wanted some precise mathematics, or if someone has found an easier workaround on the same

Comment: Do you have a screenshot of what you are trying to achieve - i take a look to your code. Except if you really have a special need for it it is not recommended to change your view frame you way you did by detecting any orientation change but again by using the autoResizingMask instead. May be can you post a screenshot of your view for each orientation?